# What happens with shared Kibana graphs when SearchGuard gets installed?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, search-guard

Couldn't find any information about this online, but does anyone know what happens to graphs that are shared on kibana (and potentially embeded elsewhere) when searchguard is installed around Kibana + ElasticSearch - will the same security happen when trying to load an IFrame with the graphs in it or does it allow you to view shared graphs?

Thanks.

Comment: it makes, security wise spoken, no difference if you load a graph in kibana directly or embed it via an iframe